# PHP: msqyl join self and LIKE query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I use below code but not work

```
SELECT `oldTb`.`userId`
FROM `user` AS oldTb JOIN
     `user` AS newTb
WHERE `newTb`.`userPrivate` LIKE "%,`oldTb`.`userId`,%"
GROUP BY `userId`
```

Actually, i want get result of users when `userPrivate` column have `,ID,` of users from self table

Example:

```
userId ---- userPrivate    
1  ---- ,0,    
2 ---- ,0,    
3 ---- ,1,    
4 ---- ,1,3,    
5 ---- ,3,
```

Now have to result is :

1 and 3

Comment: I hope this isn't a question about comma delimited data

Comment: can you post your table structure. ?

Comment: @Strawberry sorry, but it is :(

Comment: @Roshnihegde in my question i sent

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: `"%,\`oldTb\`.\`userId\`,%"` should be `CONCAT("%,", \`oldTb\`.\`userId\`, ",%")`

Comment: Fix your data!  You should not be storing *numeric* ids (which should be declared as foreign keys) as *character* values in a delimited string.  That is not the right way to store data in relational databases.